# Google Chrome default opening position and size

Tags: google-chrome, position, size, default

I am quite a highly OCD and lazy person and currently, I noticed that everyday late at night when I’m doing some work, I leave my Google Chrome split to the right of the screen and some document on the left side. When I open the browser in the morning, I have to manually resize the window length and width.

I am currently browsing the Internet to check if there is a solution to my problem and found a Google extension that does 75% of the job. It’s called [windows resizer](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/window-resizer/kkelicaakdanhinjdeammmilcgefonfh).

However, you still need to press the button in order to resize the window. I would like to override Chrome’s default settings and set a width, height, and position just like you can do with VLC player.

Comment: This is way late, but this was top result when I consulted Mr.Google so here's an easier fix than suggested below:

1. Open Chromeset window to desired size
2. Press CTRL + F5

Next time you open Chrome, the size should be what was when pressing CTRL + F5

Answer (score 17):

Maybe a little late, but I found an easier way to set the defaults! You have to right-click on the right of your tab and choose "size", then click on your window, and it should keep it as the default size.

Comment: confirmed working windows 10 chrome 63!

Comment: For me, at first I thought this worked, but then discovered Google Chrome won't make itself as large as I want if it can't determine the screen resolution when started. I've got it auto starting on boot up and if the display device isn't on, it ignores the default size.

Comment: I don't understand this answer. I clicked but nothing happned.

Comment: You need to click on the space between tabs and X button
First you need to resize your window , then the "size" option will be enabled

Comment: I tried this on chrome 86 but when I maximize the window and then click restore again it just goes back to being tiny instead of the size/position I want...

Answer (score 9):

First, close all instances of Google Chrome. There should be no instances of `chrome.exe` running in the Windows Task Manager. Then

- Go to `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\`.
- Open the file "Preferences" in a text editor like Notepad.
- First, resave the file to something like "Preference - Old" without any extension (i.e. no `.txt`). This will serve as a backup, should something go wrong.
- Look for a section called "browser." Inside that section, you should find a subsection called `window_placement`. Under `window_placement` you will see things like "bottom", "left", "right", etc. with numbers after them.

You will need to play around with these numbers to get your desired window size and placement. When finished, save this file with the name "Preferences" again with no extension. This will overwrite the existing Preferences file. Open Chrome and see how you did. If you're not satisfied with the size and placement, close Chrome and change the numbers in the Preferences file until you get what you want.

Comment: The file pathway didn't post correctly. The path should have your User ID inserted between \Users\ and \AppData\ (e.g. C:\Users\Dave\AppData\ etc.).

Comment: You may also have to change your view options in Windows Explorer in order to see the folder "AppData." This is normally a hidden file. In Windows Explorer, just go to Organize --> Folder and Search Options --> click on View tab --> change the selection for "Hidden files and folders" to "Show hidden files, folders, and drives."

Comment: Or enter %LOCALAPPDATA% in Windows Explorer to go directly to `AppData\Local` folder

Answer (score -2):

You should just grab the window by the title bar and snap it to the left side of your screen (close browser) then reopen the browser ans snap it to the top... problem is over.

Comment: Doesn't work, won't work.