# Chrome Extension: creating window at the size of the default (Ctrl+N) browser window?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, resize, window

I am writing a [Google Chrome extension](https://cxw42.github.io/TabFern) for managing tabs (inspired by [Tabs Outliner](http://tabsoutliner.com), which Chrome 60 broke).  I have a popup window showing previously-closed browser windows and their tabs:

[image: screenshot]

When I click on "Saved window", the event handler calls

```
chrome.windows.create(
        {
            url: urls,     // Array of the URLs of the tabs, here ['https://demozoo.org']
            focused: true
        },
        function(win) {
            // callback code omitted
        }
);
```

That works, but the resulting window is the same size as the *popup*, not the same size as a normal browser window would be if I hit Ctrl+N.  How can I create the window at the Ctrl+N size instead?

**Some workarounds:**

**Edit** as suggested by [wOxxOm](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3959875/woxxom), if there is a window open, I can use `chrome.windows.get()` to get its size and position, then create at that size.  However, I am looking for a solution that will work even when there is no window open other than my popup itself.  In that situation, `chrome.windows.getAll()` returns only the popup.  However, the size of the last-closed (non-popup?) window is saved somewhere, because Ctrl+N in my popup window will open a window at that size, not the popup's size.

**Edit 2** as suggested by [Mayken](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3773011/makyen), I can track the size of the most recently closed window manually, by trapping all [chrome.windows onRemoved events](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/windows#event-onRemoved).  (I would also have to track onCreated for, e.g., just after Chrome startup, before any window has been closed.)  However, since Chrome already tracks this, I am wondering if I can read Chrome's value rather than duplicating effort.

**Original** If I inspect the popup, in the console, I can run

```
chrome.windows.create()
```

and get a window that is the same size as the normal window.  However, if I provide any URL, e.g.:

```
chrome.windows.create({url:'about:blank'})
```

the window has the size of the parent popup.  As a workaround, I can use [`chrome.windows.create()`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/windows#method-create) and then manually add the tabs one at a time with [`chrome.tabs.create()`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-create).  However, I would like to keep the convenience of the `urls: [...]` parameter if possible.

Alternatively, I could create an empty window with `chrome.windows.create()`, get its size, close it, and then open the new window with the specified size.  I am not a big fan of the risk of flicker, though.

I have looked online and can't find a way to access the default size or create a window with `urls` at the default size.  The information is in the profile's `Preferences` file per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28218709/2877364), but I can't find a reliable, cross-platform way to build a `file://` URL to the profile directory.  I also cannot find an API in the [list](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/api_index) that looks like it provides profile information.

Comment: AFAICT Ctrl-N uses current window size so can't you simply read it via chrome.windows.get and provide in .create?

Comment: @wOxxOm Good point - edited.

Comment: If you are saving the tabs from a window, why are you not also saving the window size/position at the same time? As a user, if I'm asking you to save windows (and their tabs), then I certainly expect you to be saving the window size and position and to be restoring *those*, not some default size that Chrome thinks windows should be now. If you do save the size/position, then it's just a matter of restoring the size/position when you open the window.

Comment: For what you are specifically asking about: Usually, the "default" is the size of the last closed window. You just need to save the size of the last window to be closed. You can then use that size.

Comment: @Makyen **(saving size)** Sounds like a nice option - [issue open](https://github.com/cxw42/TabFern/issues/5).  However, my personal use case is different, so I am still interested in the default.  **(size of the last closed window)** Chrome already saves the size --- can extensions access the saved value?  If so, I won't have to track it manually.

Comment: @cxw, I know of no way to getting the size of the most recently closed window without opening a window to the default and then getting that window's size. Thus, my expectation is you will need to save the information while the window is open.

Comment: @Makyen given that no one else has chipped in, would you please copy or move the text of your comments to an answer?  Thanks!