# Start chromium browser in minimized state (Win32/WinAPI)

Tags: c++, c, winapi

I want to start browser in minimized state, however [in this list](https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/) there's no option for minimizing. So I thought of using `ShowWindow()` but some issues arise. I don't know how to use `EnumWindows()` or its derivatives. Only alternative I know is `GetWindow()` but I'm not sure of the position of window at Z-order. This is my solution:

```
HWND hwnd,hwnd2; //hwnd is my application's top level window
char t[128];
std::string t2;
for(int i=0; i<128&&t2!="found"; i++)
{
    if(!i||i==64) hwnd2=hwnd; //turn direction
    hwnd2=GetWindow(hwnd2,i<64?2:3); //loop backwards and forwards
    GetWindowText(hwnd2,t,GetWindowTextLength(hwnd2)+1);
    t2=t; if(t2.find("New")!=-1) t2="Found"; //Default title is "New Tab..."
}
ShowWindow(hwnd2,SW_MINIMIZE);
```

Assuming there won't be more than 128 windows, it works fine but since a window takes ~2 seconds to open, at the time ShowWindow() occurs, the window is not yet ready. So I used a timer for it.

```
SetTimer(hwnd,1,2000,0);
```

and

```
case WM_TIMER:
    KillTimer(hwnd,1);
    ShowWindow(hwnd2,SW_MINIMIZE);
    break;
```

But it's impossible to know the exact time so the window gets minimized after it's shown for some milliseconds. I tried setting multiple timers in an interval of 50ms.

```
for(int i=0; i<50; i++) SetTimer(hwnd,1+i,i*50,0);
```

and

```
case WM_TIMER:
    KillTimer(hwnd,wParam);
    ShowWindow(hwnd2,SW_MINIMIZE);
    break;
```

It usually minimizes window before it's shown, not always though. Also it changes the cursor to busy state every 50ms. Is there a way to stop this when the minimizing successfully performed once? It's not possible to determine this from the return value of `ShowWindow()` so is there a way? How can minimizing window before it's shown be guaranteed? Can I somehow make it wait till browser window is ready then sending `ShowWindow()` on the right time at once? How can I improve my solution into an easier one?

Comment: Can you share why you want to start the browser minimized?

Comment: @huysentruitw I wrote an app that logs me in to some websites automatically. While it's running, I don't want it to steal focus because I'll be doing something else on pc.

Comment: How do you start that browser?

Comment: @VladFeinstein I simply use `WinExec("chrome.exe somewebsite.com",SW_HIDE);` This runs it without console window being displayed.

Answer (score 0):

`WinExec` gives you very little control over spawned process.

Use [CreateProcess](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createprocessa), and set `LPSTARTUPINFOA  lpStartupInfo`'s `WORD wShowWindow;` to `SW_MINIMIZE`

Make sure that `dwFlags` contains `STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW`

Here is how to use it:

```
#include <windows.h>

int main()
{
  PROCESS_INFORMATION processInformation = { 0 };
  STARTUPINFO startupInfo = { sizeof STARTUPINFO };
  startupInfo.dwFlags = STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW;
  startupInfo.wShowWindow = SW_MINIMIZE;

  wchar_t cmd[] = L"C:\\Program Files\\Internet Explorer\\iexplore.exe";
  // Create the process
  BOOL result = CreateProcess(NULL,
    cmd,     // command line 
    NULL,          // process security attributes 
    NULL,          // primary thread security attributes 
    FALSE,         // handles are not inherited 
    NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS |
    CREATE_NO_WINDOW, // creation flags 
    NULL,          // use parent's environment 
    NULL,          // use parent's current directory 
    &startupInfo,  // STARTUPINFO pointer 
    &processInformation);  // receives PROCESS_INFORMATION 
}
```

**UPDATE**

In the referenced doc, they state:

> the wShowWindow member is used if the nCmdShow parameter of ShowWindow is set to SW_SHOWDEFAULT.

There is similar comment on the position and size field.

Apparently, some application do NOT use the defaults. For example, `chrome` and `calc` open their window at the position it was closed previously.

You can find that stored location in the Registry and update it.

**More info**

[Google Chrome default opening position and size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13993984/google-chrome-default-opening-position-and-size) suggests to edit `Preferences` file. It looks like this:

```
"window_placement":{"bottom":1363,"left":406,"maximized":false,"right":1356,"top":217,"visible":false,"work_area_bottom":1400,"work_area_left":0,"work_area_right":2560,"work_area_top":0}
```

I've tried to invent keys like `minimized`, `hidden`, `visible` - no luck :)

You could shift the window off-screen; I have partial success - `chrome` moves it back in so at least a few pixels show...

Comment: I can't get it working, nothing happens when it's run. Can you please write a short example?

Comment: I tried `ShellExecute()` and `ShellExecuteEx()` functions, they run but both ignores `SW_MINIMIZE` state. I still couldn't get `CreateProcess()` working.

Comment: Thank you for your help, it opens window now but still ignores `SW_MINIMIZE` just like other functions.

Comment: Can I send `ShowWindow()` externally when the browser is ready? Do `STARTUPINFO` or `PROCESS_INFORMATION` structuress provide enough information to do this?

Comment: What can be done with `hProcess` and `hThread` handles? Anything useful?

Comment: I suspected that chromium browsers can't be started minimized initially, tried with `calc.exe` but it doesn't start minimized either.

`PROCESS_INFORMATION b{0}; STARTUPINFO a{sizeof(a)}; a.dwFlags=STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW; a.wShowWindow=SW_MINIMIZE;
CreateProcess("C:\\Windows\\System32\\calc.exe",0,0,0,0,0,0,0,&a,&b);`

Comment: I think everything will ignore `SW_MINIMIZE` initially, because [here](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=40853) and [here](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=220546) are also this bug is reported. Maybe at some point of WinAPI development, they unintentionally broke this feature and it never got a fix. It may be even unnoticed.

Comment: Thanks for the new update. I think digging it further will be unnecessary and won't worth it. I'll stick with my timer loop. It's amateurish but working :)

Comment: @user814412 - sure you can retreat. But please check out my `More info` update

Comment: The reason I wanted to start it minimized is not about visibility, but about focus. Whether the window is off-screen or not, it would still steal focus once the window is initialized. I think the best is to send `ShowWindow()` in a timer loop so that once it succeeds, it gives focus back to the previously active window and this is what I intend to do. Thanks again for your time and effort sir :)